# python openpyxl bar chart set datalabels position to center

Tags: openpyxl

How can I set Bar Chart datalabels position (for instance, center).

I'm trying:

```
Bar = BarChart()
Bar.dataLabels.showVal = True
Bar.dataLabels.dLblsPos ='ctr'
```

I'm new to Python. Any help would be highly appreciated.